# Name input not going into database file upload

Tags: php, html, ajax

Could anyone tell me how to get this to work or why it isn't working? everything goes into database except $vidname, help please. as far as I can see everything is right but that $vidname just don't want to go in :(

upload_form.php

```
<script>

function _(el){
return document.getElementById(el);

}

function uploadFile(){
var file = _("file1").files[0]; //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
var formdata = new FormData(); formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
ajax.send(formdata);

}

function progressHandler(event){
_("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
_("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
_("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait while file is saved!";

}

function completeHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
_("progressBar").value = 0;

}

function errorHandler(event){ _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";

}

function abortHandler(event){ _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}

 </script> 
</head>

<body> 

<h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>

<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
Video Name:<input type="text" name="vidname" id="vidname">
File:<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
<h3 id="status"></h3> <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

file_upload_parser.php

```
include_once('config.php');
include_once('functions.php');

$vidname = makesafe($_POST['vidname']);
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen 
echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
exit();

}

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "../videos/$fileName")){
$url = "http://www.industrygaming.co.uk/videos/$fileName";
echo "$fileName upload is complete!";

$name = $fetchAccount['Name'];
$file = $fileName;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO YouTube VALUE('','$name', '$vidname','$url')");

}else{

echo "move_uploaded_file function failed"; }
```

Comment: test with out `makesafe()`

Comment: 2 things.. if $vidname is available after post and use mysql_error() to see whats going on.

Comment: I have tested without makesafe still dont work that makesafe is a security funtion I think.